# How to prove the function $x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x + 1$ is increasing for all values of $x$?

Tags: calculus

If I have the function $x^3+3x^2+4x+1$, how can I prove it is increasing for all values of $x$? I tried setting it equal to zero after differentiating it $3x^2+6x+4$, but I got an imaginary number. How do I continue with it?

Comment: The derivative is $3x^2+6x+4$, which is a convex quadratic. The $\min$ occurs at $6x+6=0$, and the value of the derivative at $x=-6$ is $76$ which is $>0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$3x^{2}+6x+4=3(x^{2}+2x+4/3)=3(x+1)^{2}+1>0$ since $(x+1)^{2} \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: So I have to try to make a perfect square if the function cannot be factorized itself?

Comment: @user1039203 The very fact that the derivative never vanishes shows that it is always positive or always negative. So if it  positive at one point you can conclude that it is always positive. But this argument requires some proof. It is easier to complete the square to see that it is positive.

Comment: @user1039203 To check if a parabola lies above the x-axis, you can also check that its discriminant ($b^2-4ac$) is negative (and that the first coefficient $a$ is positive). This comes from the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Without calculus:
$$
(x^3+3x^2+4x+1)-(y^3+3y^2+4y+1)=(x - y) (x^2 + x y + 3 x + y^2 + 3 y + 4)
$$
Now, as a function of $x$, the discriminant of $x^2 + x y + 3 x + y^2 + 3 y + 4$ is $-3 y^2 - 6 y - 7$, which is always negative. Therefore, $x^2 + x y + 3 x + y^2 + 3 y + 4 >0$ for all $x,y$.

Bottom line: $(x^3+3x^2+4x+1)-(y^3+3y^2+4y+1) > 0 $ if $x-y >0$.